# Need to protect atomic flag with condition variable?

Tags: c++, atomic, condition-variable

I write some code on VS2013, like

```
std::atomic<size_t> count = 0;
std::mutex sync;
std::condition_variable cv;
void thread1()
{
    count++;
    task();
    count--;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(sync);
    cv.notify_one();
}
void thread2()
{
     std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(sync);
     cv.wait(lock, [this](){return count == 0; });
}
```

but that code dont wait all times on

```
cv.wait(lock, [this](){return count == 0; });
```

if i change code (remove atomic flag and add mutex lock) all works well:

```
size_t count = 0;
boost::mutex sync;
boost::condition_variable cv;
void thread1()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(sync);
    count++;
    task();
    count--;
    cv.notify_one();
}
void thread2()
{
     std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(sync);
     cv.wait(lock, [this](){return count == 0; });
}
```

Is anything wrong with using std::atomic as flag ?

Comment: You don't know which thread will get executed first, so if it's thread2, then it's possible for it to complete before thread1 would even be executed.

Comment: first thread will executed first manually always.

Comment: @Andy How do you know? You can manually control your OS scheduler?